# Webpack Won't Load PNG Despite Require, Config and Modules Reinstall

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

There are several threads about this one issue, but none of them have yielded any results to me so far. As the title suggests, my React project contains an img tag, where a png is provided as it's source.

So far, I have tried using requiring the path AND importing it as a variable. I have also added the loaders in my webpack config as you can see below.

Also of note is that the dimensions are actually loaded, and when right clicking to check the image source, the website returns a **Cannot GET /[object%20Object]**

Any insight is greatly greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

**Image Tag**

```
 <img src={require('./mug1.png').default} className="mugImage" />
```

**CSS**

```
.mugImage {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

**Webpack**

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const htmlPlugin = new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
  template: "./src/index.html",
  filename: "./index.html"
});
module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  resolve: {
    fallback: {
      assert: require.resolve('assert'),
      crypto: require.resolve('crypto-browserify'),
      http: require.resolve('stream-http'),
      https: require.resolve('https-browserify'),
      os: require.resolve('os-browserify/browser'),
      stream: require.resolve('stream-browserify'),
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: {
        loader: "babel-loader"
      }
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
    }, {
      test: /\.(jpg|png|svg)$/,
      use: {
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 25000
        }
      }
    },
    {
      test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            esModule: false,
          },
        },
      ],
    },



    ]
  },
  plugins: [htmlPlugin]
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use both loaders. Both loaders [`url-loader`](https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/url-loader/) and [`file-loader`](https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/) work the same, but the difference is `url-loader` can be configured with `limit` to smaller files to be inlined like DataURL.
Like

```
data:image/png;base64,ZXhwb3J0IGRlZmF1bHQgX193ZWJwYWNrX3B1YmxpY19wYXRoX18gKyAiNDRlYTU1N2FlYmM4ZTM2Y2EyOGQ2N2RlM2YwMWM2MWMucG5nIjs=
```

Another thing is that `file-loader` emits assets to the output directory on the build.
If you choose to use `url-loader`

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      ...
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|svg)$/,
        use: [{          {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 25000 //asset size limit in byte
            name: '[name].[ext]',
            outputPath: 'assets/images/'
          },
        }]
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [...]
};
```

> Assets size lower than configured will be inlined with DataURL no asset will be emitted. Greater will be handled as a separate file.
> for `file-loader` try

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      ...
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|svg)$/,
        use: [{          {
            loader: 'file-loader'
        }]
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [...]
};
```

###### Here keep es syntax and don't change it to CommonJS by `esMoulde: false`. Remove from your code.